# How to get basic events from ExoPlayer 2?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `ExoPlayer` 2.7.1. I want to execute some code on events like `onStart`, `onStop`, `onPause`, `onResume`, `onStartAd`, `onStopAd`, `onHeartBeat`, `onBufferingStart`, `onBufferingEnd`, `onLoadingComplete`, `onBandWidthChange`, etc.

`ExoPlayer` does not have these events in their `Player.EventListener`. I want to write code using `ExoPlayer`s `EventListener` which will be the equivalent of these events. How do I do that?

Comment: @pskink I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: yes it does not have these events, so where these events did you get from? for example `onBufferingStart`, `onBufferingEnd`... why not `onBufferingComplete` for example? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink I want to write code using `ExoPlayer`s `EventListener` which will be the equivalent of these events. How do I do that?

Comment: is that what you looking for `https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#player-events` ?

Comment: where did you find those `onBufferingStart`, `onBufferingEnd` etc?

Comment: @pskink They are my own. I want to write such events using `EventListener`.

Comment: @AliEsaAssadi No. See my other comments for further explanation.